# Change CHECKOUT button text on shop page in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a problem I need to put word "Payments" instead of " Ceckout" when someone add product in cart.
is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Following code worked for me

//The filters.. both are required.
add_filter('gettext', 'change_checkout_btn');
add_filter('ngettext', 'change_checkout_btn');

//function
function change_checkout_btn($checkout_btn){
  $checkout_btn= str_ireplace('Checkout', 'Your New Text', $checkout_btn);
  return $checkout_btn;
}

Answer (score 0):

For Cart Page Try This-

```
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() { ?>
 <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
 <?php esc_html_e( 'Payments', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
 </a>
 <?php
}
```